# How to search for nested files in my S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm on the S3 Management Console and I see the instructions to type a prefix to search:

[image]

However, when I search, it only finds files in the current folder. Is there a way to search for files that might be in a nested folder?

If this can't be done from the web console. Is it possible to do it using a command line utility?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a find equivalent that I know of.  I do this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/ --recursive | grep filename
```

Answer (score 3):

From command line you can use command like:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/ --recursive "filename"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't allow the "filename". I guess I can grep the output of this call, but I was wondering if there was a `find` equivalent